# Why was the question asked first marked as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

On July 20, this question was asked:
[What is Majestic Myriarch's power and toughness if I "eternalize" it with God-Pharaoh's Gift?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/36898/what-is-majestic-myriarchs-power-and-toughness-if-i-eternalize-it-with-god-ph?noredirect=1#comment52376_36898)

Then, on August 17, this one: [Token copies with Scarab God](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/38186/token-copies-with-scarab-god)

Why was the earlier asked question closed as a duplicate rather than the other way around? This may be a targeted Meta question at ikegami, since they made the close by themselves.

Disclaimer: I asked the original question. I'm not concerned about one of my questions being closed, but I am curious why it was done in the way it was.

Comment: I don't see any good reason for your question to be closed, so I have reopened it. I think the other question should be closed as a duplicate of yours, but I haven't done so yet because I would also like to know the rationale for the original closure.

Comment: The banner directs traffic from the closed question to the open question. It would benefit the site to direct traffic from lower quality questions to higher quality questions. Therefore, we should always choose to close the lower quality question. In the rare case that both questions are of equal quality, then maybe age can serve as a tiebreaker.

Comment: And in this case I would have chosen the older one, because it seems to be of higher quality. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: I generally agree with Rainbolt here: although some elements of the UI/description do suggest that new questions will be marked as duplicates of the old, the actual goal is to send people to where they can find good answers. Frequently that does mean new to old, because old questions have had time to be polished and get good answers, but there are exceptions. Sometimes newer questions are formulated better, and attract better answers, for example.

Comment: I've only ever seen (in practice) an old question be a duplicate of a new question in the case of canonical answers.